# Can't access Odoo on Google cloud

Tags: odoo, google-cloud-storage

I have successfully installed **Odoo** on **Google cloud** (VM ware instance Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ) and started odoo service. everything seems well.

but while I am trying to access the instance from external IP it is not allowing me to access. to check whether ip is working or not I have installed apache2. but I can access apache2 default page from external IP.

have anyone installed odoo on Google cloud?

Comment: What do you mean by I can't access it. is it a 404 error, or something else? Check the port number by default is 8069, but can be changed (check odoo server config file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Google cloud by default http traffic is not allowed. you can access Apache's default page that means you have allowed the http traffic.

May be your problem is with port. you can access Apache's default page because default port of Apache is 80 and it is open.
if you are starting odoo on port default port(8069) you need to that port. for that you need run a command on terminal using root like

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

after that you can access odoo on `http://your.ip:8069`

another possible option is to redirect the port 8069 on port 80. to redirect port open a file /etc/rc.local using

```
nano /etc/rc.local
```

paste a command

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8069
```

and reboot your server using

```
sudo reboot
```

after reboot you can access odoo on default port like `http://your.ip`

Comment: Again Thanks a lot for your effort. It really helped me.

Comment: Great!! Its working on Google cloud...Please follow as is as guided

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a firewall rule to allow connections to the correct port (usually 8069 by default).

Go to console.developers.google.com and then navigate to YourProject -> Networking -> Networks -> YourNetwork

Click on 'Add Firewall Rule' and give your rule a new name, select the network, select (Allow from any source 0.0.0.0/0) and where it says 'Allowed protocols and ports' enter tcp:8069 (or other port if not on the default port).

The rule will work on all instances within that project, if you would like to limit it to a particular instance you can add a tag in the 'Target Tags' section (remember also to add the same tag to your instance).

Then click on create and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue today.
So i edited file on
     nano /etc/rc.local 
added the command

```
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8069
```

did a restart 
sudo reboot

voila ! it's fixed